# Property of continuous function on dense sets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and such that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in A$ where $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Can you deduce that $f > 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$? If not (which is my hunch), can we think of a counterexample? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. Think of a function whose graph looks like a $\bigvee$.

Comment: I would have said something like $(\sin x)^2$, which is a similar example, only that it is periodic.

Comment: Nice one! Puncturing $\mathbb{R}$ to get a dense set is a really neat trick.

Comment: I'm going to thumb this answer up, but what happens if we specify $A = \mathbb{Q}$; that is, a less innocuous $A$?

Comment: @Joshua: Same trick with an irrational offset: use $f(x)=|x-\sqrt2|$, for instance.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I like your response better than mine. It seems clearer.

Comment: @Clayton: I’m a great believer in getting lots of mileage out of simple ideas!

Comment: I guess in general the function $|x - b|$ works where $b \in \mathbb{R} \setminus A$. Sweet.

Answer (score 2):

No. Take $f(x)=|x|$ on $\mathbb{R}^*$.

But you can deduce that $f\geq 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.